# Sending email with attachment in ASP.NET MVC is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. In my project I need to send email with attachment. But when I send email, email is sent successfully but attachment is not included.

This is my send email method

```
public bool Send(string email, string subject, string body, HttpPostedFileBase fileUploader, bool html = true)
{
    try
    {
        string from = AppEmail; //example:- sourabh9303@gmail.com

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, email))
        {

            mail.Subject = subject;

            mail.Body = body;

            if (fileUploader != null && fileUploader.ContentLength>0)
            {

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.FileName);

                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUploader.InputStream, fileName));
            }

            mail.IsBodyHtml = html;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(from, EmailPassword);

            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            smtp.Credentials = networkCredential;

            smtp.Port = 587;

            smtp.Send(mail);

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Why is the attachment not included?

Comment: Set breakpoints, step through your code. Is the attachment actually added?

Answer (score 1):

**Namespaces**
You will need to import the following namespaces

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

**Model**
Following is a Model class named EmailModel with the following properties.

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(EmailModel model)
{
    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(model.Email, model.To))
    {
        mm.Subject = model.Subject;
        mm.Body = model.Body;
        if (model.Attachment.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.Attachment.FileName);
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(model.Attachment.InputStream, fileName));
        }
        mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(model.Email, model.Password);
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            ViewBag.Message = "Email sent.";
        }
    }

    return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Send_Email_MVC.Models.EmailModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        table th, table td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 80px">
                        To:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.To)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Subject:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        Body:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { rows = "3", cols = "20" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        File Attachment:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attachment, new { type = "file" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Gmail Email:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Gmail Password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { type = "password" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <span style="color:green">@ViewBag.Message</span>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried with "@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))" ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this solution:

create this class

```
public class Attachment
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

then create this interface

```
public interface IFileAttachmentService
{
    Attachments Save(HttpPostedFileBase file);
}
```

then implement the interface on this class

```
public class FileAttachmentService : IFileAttachmentService
{
    private static readonly string _folder = "~/Attachments/";

    public Attachments Save(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file == null)
            return new Attachments();

        var savePath = GenerateUniqueFileName(_folder + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

        file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(savePath));
        return new Attachments
        {
            ContentType = file.ContentType,
            Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName),
            Path = savePath
        };
    }

    private string GenerateUniqueFileName(string basedOn)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(basedOn))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("basedOn");

        return (Path.GetDirectoryName(basedOn)
            + "\\"
            + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(basedOn)
            + "."
            + Path.GetRandomFileName()
            + Path.GetExtension(basedOn))
            .Replace('\\', '/');
    }
}
```

then create this method

```
public static void SendEmail(string to, string toName, string subject, string body, string attachment)
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("Your Gemail Address", "Sender Project System Name");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress(to, toName);
    var att = new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(attachment));
    const string fromPassword = "Your pass";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        message.Attachments.Add(att);
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
```

be careful to set attachment file in the correct mode, if you do not need send with attachment file overload this method without attachment parameter.